# coordinate transformation - reparameterization map: polar coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to find the reparameterization map $\phi$ (bijective and smooth) for the coordinate transformation of a parameterized curve $\sigma(u,v)$ which is reparameterized from $\sigma(r,\theta)$. Where $\phi :(u,v) \rightarrow  (r,\theta)$ and $\phi^{-1}: (r, \theta) \rightarrow (u,v) $ and where $u = rcos\theta$ and $v = rsin\theta$.

In order to find the jacobian of $\phi$.

Does any one have any suggestions for this map $\phi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \phi: (r, \theta) \mapsto (r \sin \theta, r\cos \theta), $$
$$ \phi^{-1}: (u,v) \mapsto ( \sqrt{u^2 + v^2 }, \arctan \frac{u}{v}) $$